# How to set tab layout on top of listview but not overlaying in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-tablayout

everyone there.
I would like to ask somebody can help me solve this problem.
I wish my ListView is displayed under the bottom of tab layouts.

Here is my xml file. The ListView is behind the tab layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bone"
    tools:context=".AddNewAdmin">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabUsers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/morandi_white"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="add" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mViewpager_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It shows like below.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1QRU.png)

Another case is the ListView are in front of the tab layouts and they cannot be clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bone"
    tools:context=".AddNewAdmin">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabUsers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/morandi_white"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabUsers"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="add" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mViewpager_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It shows as [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH2v7.png)

Thank you for reading. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use more constraints to position the elements correctly.

Example given:

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/morandi_white"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

These 2 elements are both using the constraint `Top_toTopOf="parent"`
So they overlap, because they are both aligned to the top of the same ConstraintLayout.

Best approach is to start positioning the first view (=element1) at the top of the ConstraintLayout (`Top_toTopOf="parent"`) and then align the following View (=element2) with

```
Top_toBottomOf="@id/element1"
```

Element3 would be aligned under element2 with

```
Top_toBottomOf="@id/element2"
```

You can also use more ConstraintLayouts.

/> is the closing tag for the xml-Layout, if you want to position a View inside a Layout, the closing tag has to be positioned after the View element.

In the case of:

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabUsers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@color/morandi_white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Any following View element would be outside this Layout in the same hierarchy.

Comment: It seems not working as I change the constraint to let tab layout under the toolbar still cant solve the problem, the fabAdd is aslo moved to left top.